# Can you use curl to send a login post request to wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

I am currently trying to set something up that allows me to sort of remote log into wordpress, im not sure if im going about it right or if it's possible but it seems to be from a few things i've read.

Im using the code below:

```
// Get cURL resource
$curl = curl_init();
// Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://example.com/wp-login.php',
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Codular Sample cURL Request',
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
        'log' => 'username',
        'pwd' => 'password',
        'wp-submit' => 'Log In',
        'redirect_to' => 'http://example.com/wp-admin/',
        'testcookie' => 1
    )
));
// Send the request & save response to $resp
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
die(var_dump($resp));

// Close request to clear up some resources
curl_close($curl);
```

When i die var_dump it the page returns this and nothing else: `string(0) ""` that is all.

but when i remove the "pwd" field from the curl request it returns the login page along with an error message stating that the password from the password field is missing

**EDIT**

New error on successful login:

> ERROR: Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must
>   enable cookies to use WordPress.

I have no idea what this is or why its doing it

Comment: Why don't you use WordPress ReST API instead of CURL?

Comment: @libregeek because it does not support logging in, or am i mistaken?

Comment: I'm not sure what your use case is, but if you are trying to get the content from a wordpress site, then ReST API is better.

Comment: @libregeek im not trying to GET content, im trying to log in to wordpress through a site. Login with prefilled credentials -> redirect to the admin page so users can use. Basically we have a tonne of wordpress sites and it would be easier to list them all and do a 1 click login to the admin panel.

Comment: The Rest API would be the right way to do this, if it's not enough I suggest making a plugin with your own API methods. Also there is InfiniteWP (probably many other alternatives) that I used in the past for free to manage multiple wordpress sites https://infinitewp.com/

Comment: @MarkusTenghamn correct me if im wrong but i cant find any information on logging in on the Rest API, also im building an app for my company im not being asked to find an external application to handle things im being asked to integrate it into our site

Comment: @YasminFrench see Authentication for wordpress Rest API, it also suggests some plugins that would make API authentication easier https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/

Answer (score 1):

Looks like wordpress returns back a cookie that it expects to be posted in the headers or else you get this error.  I was able to avoid this by tricking it into thinking i got the cookie ahead of time:

```
$headers = array(
   "Cookie: wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check"
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

You also need to make sure you have the cookie options on

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/path/to/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/path/to/cookie.txt');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think WordPress don't let you to do this because of missing security nonce or referrer page.

My suggestion is to install/develop a plugin that supports remote login and then send the login request to your website based on the plugin structure.

You can use following function for auto login

```
function auto_login( $username ) {
    // log in automatically
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $user = get_userdatabylogin( $username );
        $user_id = $user->ID;
        wp_set_current_user( $user_id, $user_login );
        wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id );
        do_action( 'wp_login', $user_login );
    }     
}
```

Then what you need is to just call it as following:

```
auto_login('admin');
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I wasnt able to use cURL to log in, but i was able to do things a much much simpler way using the below code.

```
<html>

<head>

    <title>Crunchify Login Page</title>
    <script>
        function loginForm() {
            document.myform.submit();
            document.myform.action = "http://www.example.com/wp-login.php";
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="loginForm()">
<form action="http://www.example.com/wp-login.php" name="myform" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="log" value="admin">
    <input type="password" name="pwd" value="password">
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

This automatically submitted a login request to Wordpress with no problems and logs the user in "Granted the correct details are submitted", simple and effective and also easily scalable using frameworks like VueJS.

Answer (score 0):

I am successfully logging into WordPress using the form and the POST method. But this didn't work for sites hosted on WP Engine hosting until I added "?wpe-login=true" into form action (action="http://www.example.com/wp-login.php?wpe-login=true").

```
<form action='http://www.example.com/wp-login.php?wpe-login=true' method='post' target='_blank'>
    <input type='hidden' name='log' value='my-username'>
    <input type='hidden' name='pwd' value='my-password'>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='LOGIN'>
</form>
```